# Android - perform drag and drop programmatically

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I would like to programmatically drag one view and release it on top of another for initialization purposes, is this possible?

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to simulate a drag&drop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove Views from Layouts and add them to other Layouts (if that's what you are looking for)

```
ViewGroup oldGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.some_layout);
ViewGroup newGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.some_other_layout);

Button button = (Button) oldGroup.findViewById(R.id.a_button);

oldGroup.removeView(button);
newGroup.addView(button);
```

There is no drag&drop animation and it might give strange results but it's possible.

A `ViewGroup` would be a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and those.

---

For simulating Drag&Drop events you could call the onDragListener manually but there is one problem:

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event);
```

expects a `DragEvent` which has no public constructor so you can only call it with `null`

There might be a way to create one via a faked Parcel but that going to be ugly.

```
private void initializationTest() {
    DragEvent event = null;
    /* maybe sth like that
    Parcel source = Parcel.obtain();
    source.writeInt(1234);
    event  = DragEvent.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
    */
    onDrag(theTargetView, event);
}
```

Another possibility is maybe to create touchevents but Idk if that would work. At least the [monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) could probably do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking for the second answer out of convenience reasons, since my drag and drop listener already does everything that I need to be done, I just didn't want too much redundant code. Since there doesn't seem to be an easy/elegant solution I will probably have to do it another way

Comment: You can probably move around your the code a bit (the part that you need twice in a new method) to make it more elegant, that should always work :)

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind and what I did in the end :)